# cat command - will it overwrite?

Tags: command-line, ssh

In order to pass the contents of one file to another we can, for example:

```
cat ~/temp_minhakey.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Let's say, we need to append **more** content to authorized_keys, but we **don't want** to overwrite it.

Should we use cat again for the next keys ? Or should we flag with something specific ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
cat ~/temp_minhakey.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

appends the contents of `~/temp_minhakey.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, it does not overwrite it. This is safe.

You might be confused with a single `>` which overwrites the file. The next command will **overwrite** your `authorized_keys` file:

```
cat somefile > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: To *overwrite* the content of one file with that of another, one would typically use `cp` and not `cat`. The former can profit from file-system-specific optimizations (e. g. copy-on-write) while the latter can't.

Answer (score 7):

The last part of that command has nothing to do with cat; the >> is a shell redirect that will always append to whatever target file you are specifying.  If you used > instead, then it would overwrite the file.

There are several other shell redirects, and you will be more productive on a command line if you learn what they all are and when to use them:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections